# How to write UVM driver and sequence item for a vending machine design (interview question)?

Tags: system-verilog, verification, uvm

I was asked this question in a DV interview and I am curious to know what I missed or what can be a better way to do it . Please lend your suggestions.

Question:

I need to write pseudocode for seq item, driver and tell scenarios which I will check for verifying the following design:

A vending machine which has following :

- inputs → **amount, valid, done** and
- outputs → **soda_out, change**

A soda costs $60. Amount can be 1, 2, 5 or 10 in dollars.  Every time a currency is inserted, `valid` is high for the next cycle and once all currencies for the are inserted, `done` goes high for one cycle and `soda_out` output goes 1 if total is $60 and change comes out if its more that $60.

Here is what I wrote:

```
  class vending_pkt extends uvm_sequence_item;
  typedef enum {1,2,3,10} currency ;
  rand currency amount[]; 
  randc currency value;
  int change;
  bit soda_out;

  constraint c1 {amount.sum() >=60 ;}

  // to check if all all currencies inserted are same, i will turn this constraint on only for one seq
   constraint c2 { foreach(amount[i])
   amount[i]==value;                                
           }
   //to check if all type currencies are inserted,  will turn this constraint on only for one seq
   constraint c3 { 
                  amount.sum() with (int'(item == 1))>0;
                  amount.sum() with (int'(item == 2))>0;
                  amount.sum() with (int'(item == 5))>0;
                  amount.sum() with (int'(item == 10))>0;
                 }

   endclass
```

**DRIVER RUN_PHASE**

```
   virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase)

    seq_item_port.get_next_item(req);
    drive(req);
    seq_item_port.item_done() 

    virtual task drive(vending_pkt req)
    int i=0;
    repeat(req.amount.size())
    begin
     vif.cb.amount<=req.amount[i]
     @(posedge vif.cb)
     vif.cb.valid<=1'b1;
     @(posedge clk)
    i++;
 end
   vif.cb.done<=1'b1;

  endtask
 endtask
```

For the scenarios, I thought of checking if same kind of currencies are inserted, all different currencies are inserted or random, if sum is exact $60, if sum is $59, sum is $61.Please let me know your thoughts or test scenarios you can think of as DV person.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general thoughts.

Try to think of interesting input signal combinations to drive.  I'm mostly referring to input timing.  Drive the `amount` signal to several random values before `valid` goes high to make sure only the last `amount` is used (unless that violates the input timing specification).  Likewise with random delays between `valid` pulses.  If it legal to "mistakenly" drive `done` too soon (before $60), do that.  Also, drive `done` "too late" (after $70).

I like that you will have a sequence which sets all currencies the same and another which makes sure all 4 currencies are used.

Create a `covergroup` to make sure you hit the interesting cases: $60, $61, $62,... $69, for example.

I don't think you need a `randc` for `value`; your constraint should be sufficient to force unique values.